# Json Deserialize fails

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

Could please someone explain me why Deserialize method fails ?

```
        [Test]
        public void Serialize_Deserialize_ExpandObject()
        {
            dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
            obj.Name = "Claudio";
            obj.Age = 32;

            JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string json = ser.Serialize(obj as IDictionary<string, object>);
            Console.WriteLine(json);

            IDictionary<string, object> deserialize = ser.Deserialize<IDictionary<string, object>>(json);
            Assert.IsTrue(deserialize.ContainsKey("Name"));
            Assert.IsTrue(deserialize.ContainsKey("Age"));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though ExpandoObject gets serialized as an array (of dictionaries) rather than a dictionary.

It gets serialized as `[{"Key":"Name","Value":"Claudio"},{"Key":"Age","Value":32}]` rather than `{"Name":"Claudio","Age":32}`

I guess there is some other interface that ExpandoObject implements like IEnumerable (as well as IDictionary<>) so the Serialize method treats it as an array. The cast (`as IDictionary<string, object>`) makes no difference because it doesn't actually alter what gets passed to the Serialize method. But this all seems to contradict the documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx.

You can deserialize to `List<IDictionary<string, object>>` but I suppose thats not terribly useful.